# too big and bad quality image uploads from react-native expo

Tags: image, react-native, compression, expo, resolution

I am building an app where employees should be able to upload pictures for a product catalog for a website. The application is built with expo react-native and the camera library is `ImagePicker` and the library used for compression and resizing is `ImageManipulator`.

Inspecting some sites that also displays product catalogs I see images around `500x300` that looks crisp even when zoomed in 200% with file sizes around `40kb` [reference](https://www.streetmachine.com/shared/144/18/frog-skateboards-dino-logo-tee_580x690c.jpg). I use an iphone XR for testing and it's camera takes images in `4032x3024`, when I resize it to something remotely similar to `500x300` it looks horrendous even without compression and the file sizes are upwards of `250kb` with compression. [my image, download link](https://development-images-decent.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/77fe8526-fb09-425b-99ea-615f78ce070b)

Could it be due to the large resolution scaling, bad compression or am I completely missing something?

We are uploading the images to three seperate AWS buckets based on the resolution of the images. (For code context)

```js
export default ({ takePictureCb, clothingId }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { toast } = useToast();
  const quality = useSelector(selectQuality);

  const launchCamera = async () => {
    const image = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      aspect: [1, 1],
      allowsEditing: true
    });
    if (image.cancelled === true) {
      return;
    }
    dispatch(setLoading(true));
    const resizedImages = await getResizedImages(image, [720, 500, 300]);
    Promise.all(resizedImages.map(resizedImage => sendImage(resizedImage)))
      .then(() => {
        toast({
          message: `The images are uploaded`,
          ...successProps
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        toast({
          message: `Something went wrong!`,
          ...errorProps
        });
      })
      .finally(() => {
        dispatch(setLoading(false));
        dispatch(removeClothing(clothingId));
        takePictureCb();
      });
  };

  const getResizedImages = async (image, pixels: number[]) => {
    const promises = pixels.map(pixels =>
      ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(image.uri, [
        { resize: { height: pixels, width: pixels }, compress: quality }
      ])
    );
    return Promise.all(promises);
  };

  const sendImage = async image => {
    await uploadImage(clothingId, image.uri);
  };

  return <Button title="Open camera" onPress={launchCamera} />;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another option in `ImagePicker` changing that may help, see below:

```
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

import { config } from "@src/utils/config";

export const imagePickerConfig = (limit: number) => {
  return {
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
    allowsEditing: false,
    quality: 1,
    allowsMultipleSelection: true,
    orderedSelection: true,
    selectionLimit: config.imageSelectionLimit - limit,
  };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
allowsEditing: true,
aspect: [4, 3],
quality: 1,
});

Comment: You have not read the question whatsoever.